# How to exclude one or more file types when creating a Quilt data package from a large directory of pre-existing files

Tags: python, bash, quiltdata

If I'm creating a [Quilt data package](https://quiltdata.com) programmatically via the command line interface (CLI) or Python library for a directory with thousands of different files, and I want to exclude one or more specific unwanted file types from the data package (such as `.txt` or `.DS_Store`), how do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*[Disclaimer: I originally wrote this answer when I was working at Quilt Data]*

Create a `.quiltignore` file in a similar way that you would use a `.gitignore` file when using Git to version control your codebase. `.quiltignore` is a special file which, when included in a directory, can be used to filter out files that are included when you call `quilt3.Package.set_dir` from inside that directory. Here's a simple example:

```bash
> ls -a
.DS_Store         foo.txt         bar.txt         image1.tiff         image2.tiff
> python -c "import quilt3; print(quilt3.Package().set_dir('/', './'))"
(local Package)
 └─.DS_Store
 └─foo.txt
 └─bar.txt
 └─image1.tiff
 └─image2.tiff
> echo .DS_Store >> .quiltignore
> echo '*.txt' >> .quiltignore
> ls -a
.DS_Store         foo.txt         bar.txt         image1.tiff         image2.tiff
.quiltignore
> python -c "import quilt3; print(quilt3.Package().set_dir('/', './'))"
(local Package)
 └─image1.tiff
 └─image2.tiff
 └─.quiltignore
```

This can be used to keep non-data files or hidden OS-level files in the directory out of the data package. This is very useful when, for example, your data and your code live in the same directory [[Reference]](https://docs.quiltdata.com/advanced/.quiltignore).

The `.quiltignore` syntax is exactly the same as that of the familiar `.gitignore`. Refer to the [git documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore) for instructions on how to use it.